# HashMap is a subclass of `io.opentelemetry.api.common.Attributes`

Tags: java

With IntelliJ, on navigating to `java.util.HashMap`, `isEmpty()` is shown to override the one in `io.opentelemetry.api.common.Attributes`.

[image]

This happens when Selenium `4.1.1` is used with the Spring project.

And I wouldn't expect this hierarchy, as shown by the following case

```
var hashMap = HashMap.class;

System.out.println(Map.class.isAssignableFrom(hashMap)); // true
System.out.println(Attributes.class.isAssignableFrom(hashMap)); // false
```

And once Selenium is removed, the parents are what expected:

[image]

I am not sure how a Java base class would implement another of an external library.

Comment: Do you have Annotation Processing enabled?

Comment: @Bohemian thanks, yes, it is enabled by default. However, disabling it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: It is not enabled by default; you must have enabled it. Try disabling it and doing a full rebuild (to make sure, delete the `out` directory, or wherever your `.class` files are being stored). My guess is opentelemetry is instrumenting classes.

Comment: I see, `lombok` has enabled it. I tried with a new project, with only Spring boot and Selenium, Annotation Processing is disabled (with a rebuild after removing the `target` folder), but it is still the same, thanks.